# Android: How to change height of ListView dynamically whenever the phone's keyboard pops up or goes down?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

I have made an application which lets user chat. For showing the chat messages I am using ListView to display the messages in List items. 
I want the ListView to adjust accordingly whenever the keyboard pops up or goes down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your message..."
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:paddingLeft="22dp" />

     <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ok"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/message_listView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:stackFromBottom="true">


 </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
 The listview should occupy the whole screen whenever the keyboard goes down and it should go up above the keyboard whenever user begins typing.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to place this code in androidmanifest.xml which is related to your activity

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"

like in this

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.footmark.activity.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label=""
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"
           />
```

this above activity for example how to place